# pumping lemma misunderstanding

Tags: pumping-lemma

given this information of a language I need to determine if the language is regular or not:
[image]

I thought to Assume by way of contradiction that L6 satisfies the conditions of the pumping lemma. Let p be the pumping constant. Consider the word w = 0^(P-1)1...
Clearly w ∈ L6. Thus, by the pumping lemma, there exist x, y, z ∈ Σ^*
such that w = xyz, |xy| ≤ p, |y| > 0 where:
x = 0^m,
y =0^(p-1-m)1,z = etc, the part that left of t he word.
if we take i = 1000 for example we get that xy^1000z not in L because we get the following expression:
000000(00000...001)^1000...z (not in L6), but the solution that provided to similar question shows this:
[image]

where am I wrong in my attitude to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language is regular because of the restriction $i_2 < 99$ which makes everything finite. Once you have 99 initial zeroes, it doesn't matter how many more you have. So the pumping lemma isn't going to help. There are a few ten thousand states. Try figuring out what they are.

Comment: Thank you, for your fast answer. I see the regular expression and the 10K possibilities, I think I had problem in making assumption as to what thee partition of the word w into xyz looks like, instead of considering all possible options of partition.